# What is typings npm module for?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, typescript-typings

1) I have searched and found that this is to produce some "typescript definition file"

What is that for ?

2) Second question: Can I mix some pure JS I wrote with ionic2 typescript ?

Answer (score 0):

regarding your typings question:

When you are using 3rd party library (like jquery) you need to include a type definition file for this library. This will give typescript more information about this library and you will have an intelliSense for this library.

The typings tool is not mandatory, there are some other ways to include type definition files, but this tool make an order with these files.

It create a typings folder and all the type definition files will install into this folder. In addition it create typings.json file to track what typings we already installed.
In addition with this tool you can uninstall type definition files.

Comment: typings is essentially obsolete. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/.

Comment: Nice! Anyway, the question needs an answer since a lot of projects using typings

Comment: Sorry, so how can I use my own JS script inside an IONIC project ?